# Can´t see items in Plist

Tags: plist, uipickerview

After many searches in the internet, i´m still having problems putting my plist in my picker view. this is my plist:

```
<dict>
<key>root</key>
<dict>
    <key>roof</key>
    <array>
        <string>80</string>
        <string>100</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

my code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.myPlist = dict;


-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myPlist.allKeys]; 
return [temp objectAtIndex:row];
```

The result just shows "root"....What am i doing wrong? any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the data source delegate?

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

See this:

[When to use a plist, UIPickerView datasource help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895487/when-to-use-a-plist-uipickerview-datasource-help)

Also as a side note, why are you creating the mutable array temp? Should not be needed and would be leaking if you are not using ARC. Any questions let me know.

Comment: hello daltoniam, thanks for your help..i already have the solution. The problem was that a plist is originally a dictionary and not an array so in my .h file i used a NSDictionary variable ( NSDicionary *myplist) and then on my .m i worked my picker view methods with the NSDicitionary.